# Confusion regarding macro in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am unable to understand the return statement below; how does two macros __force __u32 work collectively like below, please help me to understand the same.

```
static inline __u32 __be32_to_cpup(const __be32 *p)
{
     return (__force __u32)*p;
}
```

Note: I might be wrong in explaining my question, so please correct.

Comment: This is actually all explained very well by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse).  I was going to write out an answer but it would basically be copy-pasting that article and cutting out a few lines.

Comment: tl;dr it's stuff to enable compile-time checks to catch attempts to treat `__be32` as `__le32` and vice versa, that relies on GCC extensions

Comment: sorry got it, i didn't click on the link earlier

Answer (score 0):

This is actually all explained very well by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse). I was going to write out an answer but it would basically be copy-pasting that article and cutting out a few lines. –  Matt McNabb